# How can i get refreshed value of flask variable with JS and show in HTML template every 30 seconds?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

This is a parking app which refresh the available parking slots every 30 seconds WITHOUT refreshing page.

This is my .py with the route and render template

```
@views.route('/')
def home():
    while True:
        try:
            token=getToken()
            if(token!='null' or token!=''):
                plazas=getInfo(token,parkingID)
        except:
            print('Error en la conexion')
            time.sleep(secs)      
                return render_template("home.html", plazas=plazas)
```

My HTML is:

```
  <script  src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/main.js') }}"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    myVar = setInterval(refresh,30000,{{plazas}});
  </script>
</head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <table>
            {% for parking in parkings %}
                <tr>
                    <td class="par"><img src={{parking.image}} alt="img"></td>
                    <td class="nombre">{{parking.nombre}}</td>
                    {% if plazas|int >= (totalplazas*30)/100 %}
                    <td class="num" style="color:#39FF00">
                    {{plazas}}</td>
                    {% elif plazas|int < 1%}
                    <td class="num" style="color:red"><p class="an">COMPLETO</p></td>
                    {% elif plazas|int <= (totalplazas*10)/100%}
                    <td class="num" style="color:red">
                    {{plazas}}</td>
                    {% else %}
                    <td class="num" style="color:yellow">
                    {{plazas}}</td>
                    {% endif %}
                    <td class="dir"><img src={{parking.direccion}} alt="img"></td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my JS:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("num");
function refresh(pl){
    elements.innerHTML = pl;
}
```

My problem is that the {{plazas}} variable always takes the initial value and is not updated every 30 seconds even if i use while true: loop in my .py.
Any help?

Comment: You need to learn more programming. Try to understand get, post, and ajax calls.

Comment: i have tried to use ajax but i have not found a good tutorial

Comment: might help you :- https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/15/how-to-implement-a-crud-using-ajax-and-json.html

Comment: btw plazas variable returns only a number which is updating every seconds, is not a json object or something like that

Comment: The KEY point, explored in the answers below, is that it is entirely up to the Javascript to call for a refresh.  Your Python is not in control of that.  Your Javascript needs to use a timer callback every 30 seconds, where it makes an AJAX request to your Python, and uses that output to refresh its information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to get the data by fetching it from javascript using `await fetch()`. You can then set up an updater by using `setInterval()`.

Flask

```py
@app.route('/refresh')
def refresh();
  try:
    token=getToken()
    if(token!='null' or token!=''):
      plazas=getInfo(token,parkingID)
  except:
    return "Error refreshing!"
```

Javascript

```js
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("num")

async function reload() {
  // make a request to reload
  const promise = await fetch("/refresh")
  // get the text from the request, alternatively you can also use .json() to 
  // retrieve json
  const text = await promise.text()
  element.innerHTML = text
}

// refresh every 30 seconds
window.onload = setInterval(reload, 30000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be updating the rendered DOM periodically.
You'll probably need JavaScript to handle that.
There are plenty of frameworks that can enable this efficiently.
Consider looking for popular solutions, like [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/) or [VueJS](https://vuejs.org/).

Comment: Can you put some example?